# How to Disable scrolling of Data-Grid in Win-forms C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, datagrid

During Run-time the Datagrid is getting scrolled and gets hidden. Screen goes blank once all the data items are hidden.

I have made the datagrid: 
ReadOnly=True,
Scroll = None,
Disable Resizing
Selection Mode=CellSelect

Comment: show your code..

Comment: Do you actually mean a `DataGridView`? Regardless, you need to provide a far more detailed explanation of the problem. You need to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) at a minimum.

Comment: just set its datasource to null and set it back after your done

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagrid.onscroll?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_DataGrid_OnScroll_System_EventArgs_, you may look on this function.